# Extract the after_commit callback from models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, metaprogramming

I'm trying to clean up some models while making my code more cohesive, gathering all things that could trigger a certain service in one place.

Some pseudo-code of what I have so far:

```
  any_commits_on User,
                 will_trigger: -> { CommonService.run!(self.id, :alive) },
                 if:           -> { self.some_association.alive? }

  any_commits_on User,
                 will_trigger: -> { CommonService.run!(self.id, :dead) },
                 if:           -> { self.whatever.dead? }

  any_commits_on Product,
                 will_trigger: -> { CommonService.run!(self.id) }
```

Then I have a method (which doesn't work, but it's a rough representation of what I want to achieve):

```
  def any_commits_on(klass, **args)
    klass.after_commit { args[:will_trigger].call if args[:if]&.call || true }
  end
```

How would be the proper implementation of `#any_commits_on`?

None of gems I found presented a straightforward way of achieving this, but I'm open to other suggestions as well.

Best.

Comment: This looks like it might work, however i can see one issue, which is `if args[:if]&.call || true`. if the `if` is missing, then it _wont_ run, which is not what you want. Instead, you could use `unless args[:if] && !args[:if].call`

Comment: Hi max, thanks for the comment. It actually doesn't work, even without the `if` part.

Comment: When you say "it actually doesn't work", can you be more explicit. what error are you getting? edit your question to include that info.

Comment: No error, nothing happens, it simply doesn't trigger the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked in the end:

```
  def any_commits_on(klass, **args)
    klass.after_commit args[:will_trigger], if: args[:if]
  end
```